# How should t be chosen such that the running time function $\Theta(n(t+n^{1/t}))$ has a minimum rate of growth?

Tags: algorithms

#### Question

Suppose we have an algorithm whose running time is $\Theta(n(t+n^{1/t}))$, where $n$ is the input length and $t$ is a positive parameter we can choose arbitrarily. How should $t$ be chosen (depending on $n$) such that the running time (as a function of $n$) has a minimum rate of growth?

#### Answer

Let $f(t) = t+n^{1/t}$, the derivative of $f(n)$ is
$$f'(t) = t'- \frac{n^{1/t} \cdot \ln n \cdot t'}{t^2}.$$

then let $f'(t) = 0$, I have $\ln n \cdot n^{1/t} = t^2$

It is right to see $n$ as a constant? And how can I solve the equation $\ln n \cdot n^{1/t} = t^2$ ?

Comment: You say that $t$ depends on $n$.  Which means $t$ is a function of $n$.  Not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formulation seems correct, and you can find a solution using [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function): you found $$ \ln n \times n^{1/t}=t^2 \Leftrightarrow {1 \over t^2}\times n^{1/t}={1 \over \ln n}.$$ Taking the square root and transforming the base from $n$ to $e$: $${1 \over t^2}\times n^{1/t}={1 \over \ln n} \Leftrightarrow  {1 \over t}\times n^{1/2t}={1 \over \sqrt{\ln n}} \Leftrightarrow  {1 \over t}\times e^{\ln n/2t}={1 \over \sqrt{\ln n}} .$$ With the substitution $x=\ln n / 2t$ we have: $$\frac{2}{\ln n} xe^x={1 \over \sqrt{\ln n}}\Leftrightarrow xe^x=\frac{\sqrt{\ln n}}{2} \Leftrightarrow x=W\left( \frac{\sqrt{\ln n}}{2}\right)$$ so $$t=\frac{\ln n}{2W\left( \frac{\sqrt{\ln n}}{2}\right)} .$$ For this value of $t$ your running time is: $$n \left( t + n^{1/t}\right)=n \left( t + \frac {t^2}{\ln n}\right) = n \left( \frac{\ln n}{2W\left( \frac{\sqrt{\ln n}}{2}\right)} + \frac{\ln n}{4W^2\left( \frac{\sqrt{\ln n}}{2}\right)} \right)$$